# Can't print full value of a field that has space using awk

Tags: awk

Hi I am trying to get the values for username column using awk.

```
Username      User ID  User RID  User Info  Default Group  Home Directory      System shell  Additional Groups  Last Modified
------------  -------  --------  ---------  -------------  ------------------  ------------  -----------------  -------------
cifsusr          2006      2001             cifsgrp        /home/cifsusr       /bin/false                       1384753795319
releaseuser2     2005      2005             releasegr      /home/releaseuser2  /bin/false                       1384512529604
reus1            2009      2002             regr           /home/reus1         /bin/false                       1384511241736
reus2            2003      2003             regr           /home/reus2         /bin/false                       1384511283150
test usr11       2007      2006             cifsgrp        /home/test usr11    /bin/false                       1384773833130
test_usr00       2002      2004             cifsgrp        /home/test_usr00    /bin/false                       1384773358129
```

But everytime I try I miss out one user names that have spaces in between,
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean the first column?

Answer (score 1):

Since each column has a fixed width, you can use the cut command with the `-c` option. With your file,

```
$ cut -c 1-14 file
Username      
------------  
cifsusr       
releaseuser2  
reus1         
reus2         
test usr11    
test_usr00
```

Or with awk you can use the [`substr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,14)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

if your username column won't be longer than the title `-------` (2nd line), you can use this one-liner

```
awk 'NR==2{l=length($1);next}$0=substr($0,1,l)' file
```

It assumes that the text was well formatted. However the length of the username could be variable. No hardcode needed.

it outputs:

```
cifsusr     
releaseuser2
reus1       
reus2       
test usr11  
test_usr00
```